# Apache solr curl commad for creating index on specific columns

Tags: indexing, solr

Enviornment - solr-8.9.0

To load a csv file having 4 columns in apache-solr 8.9.0, i am executing following curl command.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/index/update?commit=true&separator=|' --data-binary @/home/solr/CsvFile_first4Columns.csv -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

Above command is creating index over all 4 columns, but i want to create index on only first column, How can i do that?

Content of .csv file is as follows

```
Admission_number,Name,Fathers_name,DOA
536481641,Minod bhanuka,Dasun shanka,21/05/1970
28255821,Jonny bairstow,Tom banton,30/06/1982
218057537,Ben duckett,Glenn philips,28/07/1950
```

Following contents were automatically inserted by solr-8.9 in managed-schema file.

```
<field name="DOA" type="text_general"/>
<field name="Fathers_name" type="text_general"/>
<field name="Admission_number" type="plongs"/>
<field name="Name" type="text_general"/>
  ------
<copyField source="Fathers_name" dest="Fathers_name_str" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="DOA" dest="DOA_str" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="Name" dest="Name_str" maxChars="256"/>
```

Comment: how did you define your schema.xml file for the fields?

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti Thankx for reply!I didnt define schema.xml. I am directly issuing curl commands.

Comment: then you need to define the schema.xml or managed schema field and apply indexed=tru e attribute to the fields which you want as indexed

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti, Thankx for reply! I am not able to find schema.xml in conf directory, although managed-schema is present, so am i supposed to manually create schema.xml or should i rename managed-schema to schema.xml. Can you direct me to example for indexing fields of a csv file in solr-8.9?

Comment: You can use the managed schema file.

Comment: I suspect Solr is using the headers in your CSV file to decide what fields to index and store. It might be helpful to include the first one or two rows of you CSV file in the question to see if it is obvious what Solr is guessing and why.

Comment: @HectorCorrea, Thankx for reply!In solr-8.9.0, After loading the data How can i know on which fields index was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Solr guessed pretty good field types for each of your fields: `plongs` for the account number (although `plong` would probably be better), `text_general` for the name fields. It did not recognize your date field as a date so it defaulted to `text_general`.

If you only want to index one of the fields and, I assume you do want to store the other three, you would need to define the fields ahead of time (before indexing) with the proper settings.

For example the following command will define the `Admission_number` as an integer (`plong`) single value that will be stored and indexed:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
    "name":"Admission_number",
    "type":"plong",
    "multiValued":false,
    "stored":true,
    "indexed":true
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/index/schema
```

The following command will define a string field for the name, mark it as single value, to be stored (so you can retrieve it) and not index it (so you won't be able to search for it). You could use `text_general` instead of `string` and mark it as `indexed=true` if you want to be able to search for it:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
    "name":"Name",
    "type":"string",
    "multiValued":false,
    "stored":true,
    "indexed":false
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/index/schema
```

To implement this I would suggest to start from a brand new Solr core, define the fields, and re-import the data.

One last note: The extra field definitions that you see in the `copyFields` (`Fathers_name_str`, `DOA_str`, and `Name_str`) in your current maneged_schema is something that Solr does when it automatically creates a `text_general` field. The `_str` fields are string version of the field that are use for some optimizations. They won't be created when you manually define your fields.

Comment: ...Thankx for reply! A. When solr automatically define fields, will it create index for that field? As nothing was specified in managed-schema for that field....B.When solr automatically creates 'copyFields' for fieldType 'text_general; than after loading of .csv file will  index size will be highere in compare to scenario in which we manually define the fields and copyFields was not specified?

Comment: A: I don't know. It depends on what field of Solr creates and how that particular field type is defined in the schema. B: Yes, index size might be larger if it creates the additional "_str" fields but I would be surprised if it is significantly larger.